# Grid of radio buttons in Android

Tags: performance, android, xml, user-interface, layout

I want to display multiple radio buttons in a layout with multiline style as an item inside a `RecyclerView`. Look at the code I provided below and suggest how I can refactor the code to be more efficient or optimized:

Layout in XML:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_rad1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/xyz" />


<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_rad2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp_34"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/text2"
    app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/rb_rad1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/rb_rad1" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_rad3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/text3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/rb_rad1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rb_rad1" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_rad4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/text4"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/rb_rad2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rb_rad2" />
```

Inside the `onBindViewHolder()` method:

```
holder.binding.rbRad1.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                    holder.binding.rbRad2.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad4.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad3.isChecked = false
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })

            holder.binding.rbRad3.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                    holder.binding.rbRad2.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad4.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad1.isChecked = false
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })

            holder.binding.rbRad2.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                    holder.binding.rbRad3.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad4.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad1.isChecked = false
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })

            holder.binding.rbRad4.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View?) {
                    holder.binding.rbRad2.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad3.isChecked = false
                    holder.binding.rbRad1.isChecked = false
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout XML file, keep the `checked` value of all `RadioButton` to `false`.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/rb_rad1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
    android:checked="false"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/xyz" />
...
```

Inside onBindViewHolder() method, pass the clicked `RadioButton` to another method `customRadioButtonOnClick` where you'll check what value the passed `RadioButton` holds and based on that, set the `checked` values of that one or the other buttons to `true` or `false` as per your logic like this:

```
        rb_rad1.setOnClickListener {
            customRadioButtonOnClick(rb_rad1)
        }
        rb_rad2.setOnClickListener {
            customRadioButtonOnClick(rb_rad2)
        }
        rb_rad3.setOnClickListener {
            customRadioButtonOnClick(rb_rad3)
        }
        rb_rad4.setOnClickListener {
            customRadioButtonOnClick(rb_rad4)
        }
```

`customRadioButtonOnClick`

```
private fun customRadioButtonOnClick(radioButton: RadioButton) {
    when (radioButton) {
        rb_rad1 -> rb_rad1.isChecked = true
        rb_rad2 -> rb_rad2.isChecked = true
        rb_rad3 -> rb_rad3.isChecked = true
        rb_rad4 -> rb_rad4.isChecked = true
    }
}
```